# phpmyadmin page is not clickable after login

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.4

After I am logged in to phpmyadmin the page is fully loading. However when I click on any element like for example any of my databases nothing happens.
When I try to click on it by holding ctrl to open it in a new tab it works but there appears the same issue.

Here are some infromations about my environment:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server-Typ: MySQL
Server-Version: 5.7.42-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protokoll-Version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server-Character set: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

nginx/1.14.0
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.33
PHP extension: mysqli curl mbstring
PHP version: 7.4.33
```

Is there any way to fix that issue?

I already tried to reinstall phpmyadmin by purging it before but it changed nothing.

Comment: Solved it by downloading the phpmyadmin file package and just copying it into the severs folder and overwrite the existing files.

Comment: Well, you probably [don't want to install phpMyAdmin in the first place](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin) for security and convenience reasons.